# android - handle item clicks in ListView

Tags: android, android-listview

I'm using a `ListView` to display a Playlist and I use a clickable `ImageView` to stop/resume playback, currently I'm writing a custom adapter. The problem: when I click the `ImageView`, nothing happens though click events are detected as I can see in the LogCat output. What am doing wrong? Adapter code below

```
       public class AudioListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Playlist> {

Context context;
int layoutResourceId;
Playlist data[] = null;


public AudioListAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId,
        Playlist[] data) {
    super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
    this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
    this.context = context;
    this.data = data;

}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    PlaylistHolder holder = null;

    if (row == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

        holder = new PlaylistHolder();
        PlaylistHolder.imgBtnPlay = (ImageView) row
                .findViewById(R.id.imgListBtnPlay);
        holder.txtTitle = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tvListItemSong);
        holder.txtArtist = (TextView) row
                .findViewById(R.id.tvListItemArtist);

        Playlist playlist = data[position];
        holder.txtTitle.setText(playlist.Title);
        holder.txtArtist.setText(playlist.Artist);
        PlaylistHolder.imgBtnPlay.setImageResource(playlist.btn);
        PlaylistHolder.imgBtnPlay
                .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        PlaylistHolder.imgBtnPlay
                                .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.list_button_pause);
                        Log.e("onClick", "image clicked"); //Click events are detected

                    }
                });

        row.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (PlaylistHolder) row.getTag();
    }

    return row;
}

static class PlaylistHolder {
    static ImageView imgBtnPlay;
    TextView txtTitle, txtArtist;
}

  }
```

Comment: @Mover1ck you've just changed the image on click of a button....is that not happens..?

Comment: is the button's background was changed when you clicked on the item?

Comment: that's the matter. The button background does not change though click events are detected by the system

Answer (score 0):

resolved the problem by using `setImageRessource()` instead of `setBackgroundResource()` Can't explain that but it works now

Answer (score 0):

You can refresh the list using the adaptername.notifyDatasetchanged method..But unfortunatly that will also not work because when click event will be fired list cant get to know which view is clicked. either you can try using item click listener which will provide you the position of clicked item